# Post default form field value if form field is empty

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this form field `<input type="text" placeholder="" name="city" value="" />` which i am posting to a server side script for processing.However,if ever the form field is posted with empty values,i want to post default values to be posted.I was thinking that the `placeholder="value"` could be posted if when the form field is empty but the placeholder value is not posted.

Is there a solution in html5 that can enable the default values to posted when the form field is posted empty?.

Comment: How are you posting form?

Comment: Ordinarily and not using ajax.

Comment: Leave that to the server code.

Comment: I have that done on the server side but i am looking for a way to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill empty text inputs with their default value immediately prior to submitting.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });
});
```